# Getting specific object of JSON object(XML type)

Tags: java, json, xml, eclipse

```
<app:service xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"...>
 <app:workspace>
   <atom:title type="text">Data</atom:title>
  <app:collection . . .>
   <atom:title type="text">CourseContentSet</atom:title>
   <demo:member-title>CourseContent</demo:member-title>
  </app:collection>
  <app:collection . . .>
   <atom:title type="text">UnitContentSet</atom:title>
   <demo:member-title>UnitContent</demo:member-title>
  </app:collection>
 </app:workspace>
</app:service>
```

How can i get the demo:member-title?

i have tried doing this but no success...

```
         soapDatainJsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(soapmessageString);
        JSONObjectsongs=soapDatainJsonObject.getJSONObject("app:service");  
            JSONObject songs2 = songs.getJSONObject("app:workspace");
            String content = songs2.getString("app:collection")
            System.out.println(content);
```

how can i access the inner part of the XML file? through JSON.
i want to get CourseContent, UnitContent.. .etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse every depth. Try with this:

```
JSONObject soapDatainJsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(soapmessageString);
    JSONObject songs= soapDatainJsonObject.getJSONObject("app:service");
    JSONObject songs2 = songs.getJSONObject("app:workspace");
    JSONArray atomArray =  songs2.getJSONArray("app:collection");
    JSONObject atomTitle = atomArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("atom:title");
    String content = atomTitle.getString("content");
    System.out.println(content);
```